# Koa mvc application architecture

Tags: express, model-view-controller, koa

I want to use MVC pattern and Koa for my project. but I met a problem. this is the directory structure

```
| project folder  
|-- controllers  
|---- index.js  
|-- model  
|---- index.js
|-- views
|---- index.jade
|-- app.js
```

controllers/index.js

```
var indexModel = require('../model/index.js');

module.exports = function *(next) {
  var data = yield indexModel.getData();
  yield next;
  return data;
}
```

models/index.js

```
var request = require('request');

exports.getData = function () {
  return new Promise(function () {
    var options = {
      headers: {
        'X-Forwarded-For': '' // i want use Koa's this.ip here
      }
    };
    request(http://google.com, options, function () {
    })
  });
}
```

My project has a lot of Controllers and Models, I want use koa's `this.ip` in model, or pass the ip in, how to do it?

Comment: Make your `getData()` function accept an `ip` parameter, and pass `this.ip` from the generator function. `this` in the generators executed by KoaJS are guaranteed to be the application context.

Comment: @zeronone I don't want do this every time

Comment: What do you mean by everytime? Don't you want to send a request's IP address for each receiving request?

Comment: @zeronone yes, I want to send a request's IP address for each receiving request